# How do I burn Xubuntu Live CD

Tags: linux, dvd, burning, livecd, xubuntu

I downloaded the 600+ MB Xubunto ISO.  Burnt it to a DVD using Nero Burning Rom, as a Bootable DVD.  My bootup sequence won't detect XUbuntu and still only detects windows on my Hard Drive even after I set my BIOS to boot from the CDROM first.

How do I burn the Live CD with Nero?

I'm thinking maybe I should extract the contents and then burn the folder as data to my DVD.

P.S: I only have DVDs lying around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I burnt it as a Bootable DVD.

Don't do this.  The .ISO file already contains a bootable image.  This option is for creating your own bootable discs.

Search for an option in Nero to burn an image and point to the ISO file.

Comment: It worked. --Posted from Firefox UxUbuntu LiveCD--